# How to pass parameters into an addItem function (CoreData)?

Tags: swiftui, parameters

I am trying to create a notes app. I am having trouble implementing an add new note function. I want to pass in name and text as parameters. Initially the name of the note will be set (like "New note"). When I try to add parameters the project builds but does not add a new note. Any advice?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Note.name, ascending: true)])
    var notes: FetchedResults<Note>
    
    @State private var NoteIds: Set<Note.ID> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(notes, selection: $NoteId){ note in
            Text(note.name)
        }
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction){
                Button(action: newNote){
                    Label("New Note", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func newNote(){ //add new note 
       newNote(name: "New Note", text:"")
    }
```

```
private func newNote(name: String, text: String) {
        withAnimation {
            let note = Note(context: viewContext)
            note.id = UUID()
            note.name = name
            note.text = text

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unable to create note \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datacontroller class I made in a demo app I created for this question

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

struct DataController {
    static let shared = DataController()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NotesData")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("cannot load data \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your main class , I added button at bottom to add the rows , seems to work good , hope it helps

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
       
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Note.name, ascending: true)])
    var notes: FetchedResults<Note>
    
    @State private var NoteIds: Set<Note.ID> = []

    var body: some View {
        List(notes, selection: $NoteIds){ note in
            Text(note.name ?? "")
        }

                Button(action: newNote){
                    Label("New Note", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
    
        
       
        
        
    }
    
    func newNote(name: String, text: String) {
        withAnimation {
            let note = Note(context: viewContext)
            note.id = UUID()
            note.name = name
            note.text = text
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unable to create note \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func newNote() { //add new note
        newNote(name: "New Note", text:"")
    }
        
}
```

also your struct with @main

```
@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    let  dataController = DataController()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```